# WCF binding information not getting updated in WSDL (and svcinfo file on client)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't figure it out.

I've got a WCF service and I Initially had this configuration in my `web.config`

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Delivery"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="LWS.Delivery">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/LWS/Delivery.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Delivery" name="Basic"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

I was correspondingly getting the same values for endpoint name (Basic) and binding configuration (CustomTimeOut) in the service's WSDL and in the svcinfo file of a consuming client.

Here's the part of the WSDL with the expected binding and name:

```
 <wsdl:service name="LWS.Delivery">
  <wsdl:port name="Basic" binding="BasicHttpBinding_Delivery">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost/LWS/Delivery.svc"/>
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I then tried changing the binding to the following specifically changing the endpoint name and the binding configuration.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DeliverySoapBinding"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="LWS.Delivery">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/LWS/Delivery.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DeliverySoapBinding" name="DeliveryImplPort"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

However, I'm still getting the original names for the WSDL and svcinfo file. Here's what I'm expecting:

```
 <wsdl:service name="LWS.Delivery">
  <wsdl:port name="DeliveryImplPort" binding="DeliverySoapBinding">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost/LWS/Delivery.svc"/>
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

What i've tried:

- Cleaning / Rebuilding the project
- Recycling the app pool
- Refreshing the web service
- And in the case of the test client, deleting and re-adding the service reference.